# Cant create table with preparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I can't create a table in the database (mySQL), using `preparedStatement` and try to enter name of future table with `preparedStatement.setInteger()`:

```
static String queryCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE ?" +
                                 "(ID INTEGER not NULL ," +
                                 "BRAND VARCHAR(40)," +
                                 "MODEL VARCHAR(40)," +
                                 "YEAR INTEGER not NULL," +
                                 "NOVELTY BINARY," +
                                 "PRIMARY KEY ( ID ))";
```

And then I try to construct and call the statement after inputing name of table by user:

```
newNameOfTable = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Connected for saving data. " +
                                "Input name of new table:");

                        pStatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryCreateTable);
                        pStatement.setString(1, newNameOfTable);
                        pStatement.executeUpdate();
```

It works well if I try to execute it without entering name (like a constant string: "CREATE TABLE newtable (...)" but I need to enter name..

Comment: SQL doesn't allow for the names of tables or columns to be enterred as parameters.

Comment: why dont you get the name of the table first and then create your query string?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208442/using-prepared-statements-to-set-table-name

Comment: Also see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910891/can-i-create-a-mysql-table-using-a-pdo-parameterized-statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to format the string after reading the table name, something like:

```
static String queryCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE {0}" +
                                 "(ID INTEGER not NULL ," +
                                 "BRAND VARCHAR(40)," +
                                 "MODEL VARCHAR(40)," +
                                 "YEAR INTEGER not NULL," +
                                 "NOVELTY BINARY," +
                                 "PRIMARY KEY ( ID ))";
```

then create like:

```
newNameOfTable = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Connected for saving data. " +
                            "Input name of new table:");

statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.execute(MessageFormat.format(queryCreateTable, newNameOfTable));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
newNameOfTable = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Connected for saving data. " +
                                "Input name of new table:");

static String queryCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE " + newNameOfTable +
                                 "(ID INTEGER not NULL ," +
                                 "BRAND VARCHAR(40)," +
                                 "MODEL VARCHAR(40)," +
                                 "YEAR INTEGER not NULL," +
                                 "NOVELTY BINARY," +
                                 "PRIMARY KEY ( ID ))";


pStatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryCreateTable);
pStatement.executeUpdate();
```

PreparedStatement example:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html

Comment: This does not fix the problem OP is having. He is wanting to use a PreparedStatement to prevent a MySQL injection attack. By simply appending the name of the table as text to the command, an attacker could input something in a way that allows him to run a command he should not be allowed to run. E.G., querying for other users' data or God forbid dropping a table or deleting an etire database.